# Getting IllegalArgumentException while using jcache with hazelcast

Tags: java, caching, spring-boot, hazelcast, jcache

I am trying to use jcache with hazelcast server provider. But getting this exception.

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find cache named 'xyzCache' for Builder throws caches=[xyzCache] | key='' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false'
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheResolver.resolveCaches(AbstractCacheR esolver.java:81)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.getCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:242)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CacheOperationContext.<init>(CacheAspectSupport.java:675)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.getOperationContext(CacheAspectSupport.java:255)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CacheOperationContexts.<init>(CacheAspectSupport.java:581)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:327)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
```

Here is the java configuration that I am using to configure hazelcast.

**HazelcastConfiguration.java**

```
    @EnableCaching
    class HazelcastConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Config getConfig() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Config config;

    if ((xmlConfigLocation == null) || (xmlConfigLocation.isEmpty())) {
      // use default Hazelcast configuration
      config = new Config();
    } else {
      // overlay custom xml config on default Hazelcast configuration.
      config = new FileSystemXmlConfig(xmlConfigLocation);
    }
    //Trying to create cache config 
    MapConfig cache = new MapConfig();

    cache.setName("xyzCache");
    cache.getMaxSizeConfig().setSize(1);
    cache.setMaxIdleSeconds(0);
    cache.setTimeToLiveSeconds(86400);
    cache.setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU);
    config.addMapConfig(cache);
    }
    }
```

**Dependency used:**

```
    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>  
          <artifactId>hazelcast-spring</artifactId>  
          <version>3.6.8</version>  
       </dependency>  

    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>  
          <artifactId>hazelcast-cloud</artifactId>  
          <version>3.6.8</version>
       </dependency>
```

Spring Boot Version: 1.4.6

Using these configuration, i am able to create and use hazelcast cache in application. After adding below dependency to provider jcache cache provider. Spring boot trying to use JCacheCacheConfiguration from its autoconfiguration and its cache manager.

```
    <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
          <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
       </dependency>
```

Spring Boot starts the application without any exception or error. But as soon as i try to run first api call, it starts throwing me above exception. Any advice.?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you configure the cache via `MapConfig`. 
Try to use the config object that returns from `config.getCacheConfig("xyzCache");` method in your configuration section, then let's see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Does it mean that jcache with hazelcast works when any cacheconfig is set? What if we have to use MapConfig then it will not work..?

Comment: Map and Cache are different data structures in Hazelcast. If you configure MapConfig and call cache with the same name, you will get a null.

Comment: Yes, i am getting null while configuring the MapConfig. Is there any way to stick with MapConfig while configuring jcache with hazelcast.?

Comment: No it is a seperate data structure like IQueue. But why do you need to do IMap configuration while using ICache? Is there any requirement that MapConfig provides but not the other?

Answer (score 0):

Method for setting cache instance is ***config.setInstanceName("xyzConfig")*** on ***Config***

So Full code should be like:

```
@EnableCaching
class HazelcastConfiguration {

@Bean
public Config getConfig() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Config config;

    if ((xmlConfigLocation == null) || (xmlConfigLocation.isEmpty())) {
      // use default Hazelcast configuration
      config = new Config();
    } else {
      // overlay custom xml config on default Hazelcast configuration.
      config = new FileSystemXmlConfig(xmlConfigLocation);
    }

    config.setInstanceName("xyzConfig");

    //Trying to create cache config 
    MapConfig cache = new MapConfig();
    cache.getMaxSizeConfig().setSize(1);
    cache.setTimeToLiveSeconds(86400);
    cache.setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LFU);

    // This were you put cache key and value
    config.getMapConfigs().put("xyzCache",cache);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the `javax.cache::cache-api` artifact is not in your classpath, Spring Boot backs the cache with a Hazelcast `IMap`, so your `MapConfig` is picked up and configures an `IMap` that holds the cached results for your `Cacheable` method.

Once the JCache API is located in the classpath, then it attempts to use Hazelcast as a JCache implementation (see [1]). In this case, Spring's `JCacheCacheManager` attempts to get a `Cache` already known to the JCache provider, so you need to configure Hazelcast for the cache names you declare in your `@Cacheable` annotations (see [2] for Hazelcast JCache configuration). For example, for the programmatic configuration you originally posted, when `javax.cache::cache-api` is in the classpath you need to configure Hazelcast as follows:

```
@Bean
public Config getConfig() {
    Config config = new Config();
    // do your file stuff here
    CacheSimpleConfig cacheConfig = new CacheSimpleConfig();
    cacheConfig.setName("xyzCache");
    // set other options here
    config.addCacheConfig(cacheConfig);

    // alternatively to creating CacheSimpleConfig and adding it:
    // config.getCacheConfig("xyzCache").setBackupCount(1).set...;
    return config;
}
```

[1] https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-caching-provider-jcache

[2] http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9/manual/html-single/index.html#configuring-for-jcache